# 10V DC Linear power supply

Tags: analog, output

Currently I am using an Allen Bradley Analog output card to get a variable -10VDC to +10VDC output as defined by the PLC program. However the PLC will only supply 100ma with that voltage. The device that I am providing power to requires 350ma. Is there a way I can "Amplify" the current output to the required 350ma while still providing the -10v to + 10v (variable) range required by the device? (The device in question regulates speed and direction of a hydraulic unit. It currently operates, but at a reduced speed due to the lack of current).

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is something that you want to build yourself?  If so, pound the following string into Google: "power op-amp" and choose a suitable device.  You will also need to purchase a plus minus power supply of the appropriate voltage and current.

One of the first power op-amps I saw is TI's OPA561.  However, there is a plethora of different models available from a variety of manufacturers.

FWIW: the OPA561 is good for up to 1.2 Amps at with power supply of plus minus 15 Vdc.

Comment: But also be aware that you'll need to provide another, beefier, +/- 15 volt supply. The combination of power supply, amplifier and heat sink/cooling may come as an unwelcome surprise.